# Tracking GA event for internal links... but on the next page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to track the conversion rate of people clicking my sidebar 'recent posts' widget, as well as which box they clicked on (1-10). I want to do this via the following code:

`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Sidebar Clicks', $(this).data('widget-index')]);`

I don't want this to go on a `.click()` event though for the anchor because it would delay the click.

I was thinking of trying to track it on the page AFTER they click. The links all point to my own server, so they aren't external, and I could run code.

I was thinking maybe pushing it to a cookie, and then if, on the next page, it recognizes a cookie, then it calls the track event line.

Does GA have something like this already built in, maybe with the array push function? I would love to piggyback off code has already written.

If they don't have it, then how can I solve the problem that the event will be getting sent  on the wrong URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get that info without event tracking two ways.

First - You can see the links clicked on your site using in-page analytics. Here is the all the info about it https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558811?hl=en

Second - can you add a parameter to the URLs in your recent posts? That way you can see them in the visitor flow reports and landing pages. You can also set up a custom report to only show the pages with a certain parameter.

The second option would be more exact, I've see in-page analytics get a little confused when similar HTML elements get clicked and don't have unique ID's.